# apollo client- [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400]

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

getting right data in apollo /graphql link

however doing same mutation query from client.... i am getting this error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400]
```

mygraphql query:

```
const POSTMESSAGE = gql`
  mutation sendChatMessage($data: SendMessageInput!) {
    sendMessage(data: $data)
  }
`;
```

useMutation method inside reactnative component:

```
  const [sendMessage, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(POSTMESSAGE);
```

Mutation method call from componet:

```
sendMessage(message);  //correct msg has been passed
```

i am only getting status code 400.... descriptive error might be helpful. i got this from doc but do not know how to or when to call errorLink, does this even work?? or are there other solution??

```
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) graphQLErrors.map(({ message }) => console.log(message))
})
```

**Update:**
i used errorLink, httpLink to get exact network error and here is my error:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$data" of required type "SendMessageInput!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
[Network error]: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400]
```

Note: i am using same mutation and query variables as in "/graphql" link interface where it is working.

here is my apollo client setup file:

1. App.js:

```js
     import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    import {
      ApolloClient,
      InMemoryCache,
      ApolloProvider,
      HttpLink,
      from,
      gql,
      useQuery,
      useMutation
    } from "@apollo/client";
    
    import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
    import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
    
    const httpLink = new HttpLink({
      uri: "http://localhost:9543/graphql",
    });
    
    const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      console.log("on error function called");
      if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
          )
        );
    
      if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    });
    
    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <ComponentA />
        </ApolloProvider>
      );
    }
```

2. component file where i am using useMutation

```js
 import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
    import { gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
    
    const POSTMESSAGE = gql`
      mutation sendChatMessage($data: SendMessageInput!) {
        sendMessage(data: $data)
      }
    `;
    
    const ComponentA = () => {
      const [sendToMessage, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(POSTMESSAGE);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        sendToMessage({"data":{"ChatMessageInput":[{"_id":"307abdf5-5ca9-41c5-b019-837c51de5068","createdAt":"2021-08-12T23:41:41.594Z","text":"Aaa","user":{"_id":"123"}}],"to":"456"}})
      }, [])
    
      if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
      if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Hello world</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    
    export default ComponentA
```

Comment: Where are your variables with `data` defined in the graphql payload? Oh, this is react native client, not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

was missing:  variables in the mutation syntax.
got help from apollo client community:
https://community.apollographql.com/t/apollo-client-unhandled-promise-rejection-error-response-not-successful-received-status-code-400/1103/3

```
useEffect(() => {
  sendToMessage({ 
    variables: { 
      data: {
        ...
      }
    }
  })
}, [])
```